# Determining whether the mean of a set of non - independent values is statistically different from zero

Tags: r, python, biostatistics, independence

There are some areas of statistics that I am fairly confident with, and others, that are probably very simple that I am fairly clueless about. Only one way to go but up though.

I have the dataset below, that contains 100 rows

```
X
0.285
-0.397
0.371
-0.794
0.814
0.384
-0.11
0
0
0.271
-0.572
0.419
...
```

I am working on bacterial genetic divergence. To do this I generate two datasets, with divergence data of paired bacterial species.

Example: species X with species Y, using species X site frequency spectrum, and species X with species Y using species Y site frequency spectrum.

From these dataframes I select a number of random genes with replacement 100 times. The number of genes taken is as equal to the length of the original dataframes. Once processed I end up with two sets of adaptive coefficients known as omegaA1 and omegaA2, ideally these should be equal to one another. I subtract them to create the 100 values I've alluded to. In doing so I can present the differences between OmegaA1 and OmegaA2. From here I need to determine if these values are statistically different to 0. As such I believe my results are not independent, as they’re derived from the same source. Correct me if I am wrong though, this would make my life a lot easier.

I need to determine whether the mean of these values are statistically different from zero or not in either Python of R. In python I have determined, the 95% confidence interval, with the lower 2.5% boundary being: -0.971, and the upper 95% boundary being: 0.95. As such, I know that zero falls within the 95% confidence interval.

However, I don't know how to determine whether the mean of these values are statistically significantly different from zero, with a p-value. Whilst I don't particularly like p-values, I've been told it is necessary.

I initially thought of using a one-sample t-test, which would be simple enough, however I realised that I could not as the values in the dataset are not independent of one another, as they are derived from bootstraps of a previous dataframe. As such does anyone know a suitable test or procedure to get a p-value signifying whether this dataset is statistically different from zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. If I've missed a question just like this, please by all means, just post a link. If it helps, I'll mark it as answered. I apologise if this isn't very clear. Please ask questions for the sake of clarity, writing is a struggle of mine.

James

Comment: By successively deleting previous versions of this question, you have removed useful comments placed there by others.  Please don't do that: instead, when you want to modify or improve a post, *just edit it.*  See our [help] for more information about how this site works.

Comment: Previous answers, presented flaws in my question, and I had the option to delete it and rewrite my question taking the criticism onboard. The other comment told me that these values are independent, when my own supervisor tells me they aren't. I intend to discuss this with him, but for now I intend to work, based on the assumption that he is correct, and seek to find an answer to my initial question. If I later find out that he has changed his mind, then this isn't an issue, as I know how to deal with that. Ultimately, it doesn't hurt anyone for me to pose the above question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure exactly how you obtain your data, your experiment was not really clear to me. However some remarks:

- How do you obtain the confidence interval ? It is as hard to make confidence interval as it is to find a p-value, there is a sort of duality tests-confidence interval if you can do one, you can do both in most cases. And hence, I wonder how you did your confidence interval with non-independent data ?
- If I understand right, you want to test whether $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are close to $0$, knowing that they are not independent ? Maybe you can do the following test:
  $$H_0 : \Omega_1 =\Omega_2 = 0 \quad \text{vs}\quad  H_1: \Omega_1 \neq 0 \text{ or } \Omega_2 \neq 0 $$
  and this can be done for example if your data is Gaussian (jointly Gaussian, they do not need to be independent) using [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test(s)_on_multiple_parameters) where the matrix $R$ is the identity matrix. Then, the p-value would be obtained using the chi-square quantile function (this can be easily codded in R).

Comment: Specifically I want to know whether my final dataframe which is: Ω1 - Ω2 is close to zero

Comment: In that case, you can use Wald test with $R$ equal the line vector $(1,-1)$ (cf wikipedia link I gave to see what is the R vector I speak about).

Comment: Would the wald.test function in R be a suitable way for executing your suggestion? Then if I use the chi-squared function all this can be done in a single loop. I have 20 of these dataframes. Each one is irrelevant to one another, so I just have to repeat the process 20 times, and record which ones are suitable for further analysis and which ones aren't

Comment: I imagine it wald.test can be used but I don't know exactly what it does, I always did my Wald tests by hand using the pchisq R function to get the p-value. But indeed, wald.test can be used to get the p-value according to R manual but I don't understand exactly the parameters of this function so I can't tell you exactly the command you need.

Comment: This has all been really helpful, if it works then excellent, and if it doesn't then I've learn't something new and hopefully I'll get another clue on where to go next. So either way i'm grateful, thanks!